# YouTube for Android TV app can't exit

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

When YouTube for Android TV app is launched with an intent from a third-party app then exiting from the app does not work. Both using the remote control back button and waiting for video to end fail there.

[createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)) is used with *finishOnEnd* argument set to *true*

The problem appeared after YouTube app was upgraded to version 2cf52588

From [YouTube Android Player API How to Get Help](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/support) page:

> We support the YouTube Android Player API on Stack Overflow. Google
>   engineers monitor and answer questions with the android-youtube-api
>   tag.

Therefore a question to Google engineers: will it be fixed?